# Как выбираются ресурсы для разных размеров экранов?

Tags: android, android-layout

Имеется приложение, которое написано под определенный экран. Поставлена задача сделать так, чтобы приложение корректно отображалось на всех экранах.
Читала мануал на developer.android.com, поместила в drawable папки с разной плотностью, напихала туда 9patch картинок - хорошо, фон растягивается, картинки более менее адекватны. Wrap_content используется, кое где жестко прописаны отступы, но они в dp - это тоже неплохо.
Проблема на небольших экранах в том, что контента как будто слишком много и он накладывается друг на друга, и текстовые поля не помещаются.
Для примера разметка одной активити

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/about_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/main_blurred"
android:drawableRight="@drawable/color_layer"
tools:context="ru.novocomments.terminal.AboutActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:paddingTop="69dp"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/color_layer"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout">

</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/top_row"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp">
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/circle_top"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/circle_left"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/close_right"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|left">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/about_circle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/about_circle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/about_label"
        style="@style/NCTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="@string/about" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/back_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/back"
            style="@style/NCBack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/back" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

У меня возникает мысль, что надо переписать конкретную разметку под экраны. Читала, что надо плодить папки layout-small, layout-midium, layout-large, и в них создавать хмл. Правильная ли это мысль? Или можно как то по другому решить проблему?

Comment: Мысль правильная! Можно даже изменять расположение контента в зависимости от размеров экрана девайса.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как тогда хмл обзывать? Ведь нужно, чтоб название файла было такое же, но так не получается...

Comment: Все верно, файлы должны быть в разных папках, но с одинаковыми названиями. Папки называйте layout-xlarge, layout-large, layout-normal, layout-small.

Comment: но это старый вариант, лучше использовать layout-sw<N>dp где <N> - это найменьшая ширина

Comment: Спасибо, я попробую и так и сяк. Очень помогли:)

Comment: :( получается, что dp примерно одинаковое, а диагональ разная((( и планшет и телефон один layout используют. Можно ли как то это исправить?

Comment: попробуйте в папке без идентификатора писать под телефоны, <N> - 600 для планшетов 7", 720 под 10"

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: до меня дошло (как до жирафа). Надо думать так: если ширина n или больше - используется данный layout. А я думала, наоборот. Так работает, спасибо.

Answer (score 6):

Так как существует огромное количество Android-устройств с самыми разными параметрами конфигурации экрана - физический размер, плотность пикселей, ориентация (альбомная или портретная и тд.), то требуется какое-то решение, позволяющее программисту наиболее просто учесть все это многообразие, чтобы на всех типах устройств вашим приложением было комфортно пользоваться.
В Android для решения этой проблемы используется система квалификаторов ресурсов.

Программист указывает в коде одно определенное имя ресурса, а система, с помощью квалификаторов, подбирает наиболее подходящий для конкретной конфигурации текущего устройства ресурс, например, разметку экрана.

Система квалификаторов действует следующим образом - есть список [заранее определенных квалификаторов](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers), определяющих определенные параметры экрана, такие, как размер, плотность, ориентация и тд.
Задача программиста, создать дополнительные папки ресурсов с постфиксами квалификаторов, для которых необходимо иное, чем по умолчанию (папка без каких-либо квалификаторов - будет использоваться, если никакое специфичное расположение не подходит под текущюю конфигурацию), расположение элементов, отступы и прочее, что позволит отобразить в данной конфигурации экран наиболее корректно.
Имя файла ресурса указывается такое же, как и для состояния по умолчанию, чтобы система понимала, что требуется тот же самый файл, но для определенных параметров.
В одной папке может быть указано более одного квалификатора, для указания нескольких специфичных параметров одновременно. Например:

`/res/layout/main_screen.xml` - разметка экрана по умолчанию, для всех не указанных специально конфигураций.

`/res/layout-small/main_screen.xml` - разметка для экранов с маленьким  физическим размером.

`/res/layout-large-land/main_screen.xml` - разметка для экранов с большим физическим размером и в альбомной ориентации.

Как можно заметить, имя файла ресурса одно и то же, оно же указывается и в коде для определенно экрана, без каких-либо дополнительных указаний о параметрах конфигурации устройства. Система сама определит, на основе текущей конфигурации, где запущенно приложение и указанных квалификаторов, какой из множества разметок с таким именем подходит для данного устройства.

При этом разметки конкретных конфигураций могут значительно отличаться от дефолтной, размерами элементов, компоновкой, отступами и тд., чтобы именно в текущей конфигурации все выглядело удобным для использования - единственное условие, все виджеты (элементы разметки), к которым обращаются из кода, должны присутствовать на этой разметке, иначе приложение попросту "упадет" не найдя нужного элемента.

Так же, для файлов разметки принято указывать квалификаторы физических размеров (-small, -large, -sw<> и тп.). Для графических файлов (картинок) - плотности (-hdpi, -mdpi и тп.)

Выбор конкретного квалификатора осуществляется иногда по довольно запутанной схеме. Общее правило такое, что производится сканирование по иерархии, указанной в [таблице](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers) - сверху - вниз, до первого совпадения, наиболее приближенного к текущей конфигурации устройства. Если ничего не найдено - используется ресурс по умолчанию (без квалификаторов).

Конкретное действие каждого квалификатора, какую часть конфигураций он "контролирует", указано в [таблице](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers).

Наиболее полно данный материал изложен в [официальной документации Android](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers)

Answer (score 4):

Да, если много компонентов - то для маленьких экранов придется сделать отдельную разметку, перенести xml файл с тем же именем в папку layout-small. либо как вариант оберните ваш LinearLayout в SwipeLayout, чтобы он скроллился