# Как получить размер картинки в CardView

Tags: android, bitmap, cardview

В своем приложении я сделал активность с CardView элементами с картинками. Дело в том, что картинки имеют очень большое разрешение. Чтобы загружать картинки в память эффективно, мне нужно уменьшить их разрешение под то, что будет у CardView на каком-то устройстве. Как узнать, какой размер будет иметь изображение в CardView программно?

Comment: откуда эти картинки? они заранее размещены на устройстве или скачиваются откуда-то или как?

Comment: @pavlofff они находятся в res/drawable

Comment: Для решения вашей проблемы есть так называемые квалификаторы. Вы размещаете изображения подходящего размера в папках с сответствующими квалификаторами например, для экрана HDPI в папке /drawable-hdpi/ Система сама выберет нужное изображение.

Comment: Смотрите [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453000/177345)

Comment: @pavlofff я хочу без квалификаторов. Дело в том, что в моем приложении в будущем картинки будут загружаться пользователями. Они же не будут под разные разрешения делать разные картинки и всех их отсылать. Они будут кидать одну картинку высокого разрешения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получите размер контейнера (px)

`cardView.getMeasuredWidth()` - ширина

`cardView.getMeasuredHeight()` - высота

Загрузите картинку с сети:

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

Изменение размера:

```
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
int width = bm.getWidth();
int height = bm.getHeight();

float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
return Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
}
```

Используем всё вместе, после загрузки:

```
img_1.setImageBitmap(getResizedBitmap(bitmap, cardView.getMeasuredHeight(), cardView.getMeasuredWidth()));
```

Чаще всего серверная часть имеет возможность дать ресурс уже подходящего размера и формата, есть смысл предварительно делать правильный запрос на получение более подходящего. Желательно, чтоб работа по компрессии или декодированию, проходила в отдельных потоках, ну это уже вам решать. Это простой пример, без использования lib.

Comment: большое спасибо, очень хороший, развернутый ответ)

Answer (score 2):

Нашел интересную вещь, решил ответить прямо сюда же, вдруг кому пригодится.

- **Universal Image Loader.**

Суть в том, что UIL изменяет размер изображения точно под размер контейнера изображения. Вот ссылка https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader