# Разрешения экранов

Tags: android, xml, dpi

Проблема заключается в том что на одном устройстве макет выглядит так как нужно, а на другом, примерно с такими же характеристиками но меньше диагональю, очень криво. Как это решить я не знаю. Я думаю фрагменты здесь не помогут. И да, я указывал все размеры Кнопок, Текстов и много другого в dpi. Если кто сталкивался с такой проблемой, помогите пожалуйста!)

Comment: Если вы это не читали https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html то первым делом нужно изучить то, что там написано!

Comment: Покажите разметку и скрины. Вы что то не так сделали

Comment: *расширение* - это несколько букв после точки в имени файлов. `gta5.exe` - `exe` - Расширение. А то, о чем вы говорите, называется *разрешение*

Comment: Вам нужно использоыать относительные , а не абсолютные размеры: wrap_content, match_parent, layout_weight и т.п. вместо dp

Comment: смотрите по адаптивной верстке [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345). Там основные моменты и пара примеров. Так же по квалификаторам ресурсов [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453000/177345). Возьмите почитайте хорошую книжку по разработке - Брайна Харди, Рето  Майера, Пола Дейтела, там уделяется внимание верстке и вообще узнаете много нужного и интересного, в отличие от инет-ресурсов.