# Drawble , почему для xxhdpi экрана коэффициент масштабирования 2,5 а не 3?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, display, dpi

Вот для удобства: https://gyazo.com/695dea42c3667aea2cbba9ee8ced928f
        Есть эмулятор с разрешением экрана 1080x1920 ,  5,5 дюймов, а значит плотность пикселей 400. Я добавил в папку изображение шириной 1080 px и андроид при загрузке изображения в битмап уменьшил  ширину до 900 пикселей.
Вот параметры экрана который выдаются при выполнении:

```
   DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
   System.out.println("РаЗМЕР" + metrics);
```

Параметры

```
 DisplayMetrics{density=2.5, width=1080, height=1800, scaledDensity=2.5, xdpi=400.0, ydpi=400.0}
```

Почему то density 2,5 вместо 3 для xxhdpi (плотность от 400 до 560 пикселей на дюйм) 
Берем 1080 делим на 3, и получаем размер Mdpi изображения 1080/3 = 360. Коэффициент масштабирования 2,5 (почему то) . Умножаем : 2,5 *360 = 900 . Становится понятно почему изображение сжалось . Хотя экран Телефона имеет разрешение 1920x1080 и диагональ 5,5 вместо коэффициента масштабирования  3 , андроид использует 2,5 . Вопрос : Почему ?
Объявил и инициализировал

```
Bitmap field; 
field = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.gamefield);
System.out.println("ширина  "+field.getWidth());
```

размер изображения становится меньше, чем того ,что лежит в папке drawble-xxhdpi

Comment: Не совсем в тему, но `height=1800` получается из-за того, что Вы получаете высоту экрана без учета status bar, и, вроде, без учета action bar.

Comment: Честно, три раза читал, так и не понял как это "андроид решил увеличить ширину"? И в какую конкретно папку добавлено изображение? Как отображается?

Comment: я ошибся,дважды, во первых ночью  я в цифре 1800 видел 1080 , так бы я понял что дело в статус барах возможно. А во вторых я добавил в папку drawble , без добавки -xxhdpi , а просто папка drawble по дефолту читается как mdpi, поэтому он и растягивал моё изображение в два с половиной раза. Теперь когда разобрался проблема сформулировалась иначе, я внес поправки в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За значение density = 1 принимается [размер экрана](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#density) 160dpi. Ваш размер экрана - 400dpi. Соответственно получаем: 400/160 = **2.5**. При этом данный параметр вычисляется из значения текущей плотности пикселей устройства и никак не связан с такими понятиями, как экран XXHDPI

Сама по себе загрузка изображения в `Bitmap` не должна приводить к изменению размера изображения в пикселях, поэтому стоит учесть следующее:

Папка */drawable* не читается по умолчанию, как *-mdpi* -  ресурсы этой папки берутся "по умолчанию", когда нет более точного соответствия текущего экрана с каким либо квалификатором.

Далее, на вашем скриншоте указаны коэффициенты пропорционального увеличения размера изображения программистом, для наиболее приемлемого отображения на экранах с определенной плотностью, а не коэффициенты увеличения устройством. То есть, если изображение для экрана MDPI у вас имеет размер 100х100 пикселей, то чтобы оно так же (приблизительно) смотрелость и на экране XXHDPI, то в папку */drawable-xxhdpi* нужно поместить аналогичное изображение, но размером 300х300 пикселей. Вот что значит эта таблица.

Изображения в папках ресурсов не масштабируются в назначенную квалификатором плотность. То есть, изображение из папки с квалификатором *-xxhdpi* не увеличивается в 3 раза, а наоборот, изображение в такой папке должно быть в три раза больше, чем в папке *-mdpi* изначально (при подготовке ресурсов) - эту работу делает программист, а не система.

В любом случае, какого бы размера не были ваши изображения, они не будут масштабироваться от размещения в папках квалификаторов и будут выводиться на экран "как есть". Единственная функция квалификатора - указать системе, что если плотность, к примеру, 400dpi, то картинку брать из папки с квалификатором *-xxhdpi*, если она есть (а не увеличивать ее в 2,5 , 3 или сколько ли бы ни было раз). Если подходящего квалификатора нет, то брать из папки */drawable*. При этом, если в папки поместить одинаковые изображения (по размерам в пикселях), то на одном и том же  экране они будут выглядеть одинаково.

Проблемы не соответствия связаны с разметкой, которая масштабирует исходное изображение под размеры виджета на экране, параметров масштабирования, установленных для этого виджета и реальными размерами рабочего экрана (в котором не учитывается место, занятое навигационной панелью для телефонов без мех.кнопок, статусбаром и экшенбаром), но ни каким образом не с квалификаторами.

Проблемы с размерами - результат подгонки изображения под текущий экран, чтобы оно вошло целиком в отведенное виджету место с сохранением пропорций этого виджета (так как высота виджета меньше высоты всего экрана, а изображение имеет высоту, равную высоте экрана, то оно пропорционально масштабируется под виджет - уменьшение высоты приводит и к уменьшению ширины для сохранения пропорций). То есть вы пытаетесь поместить изображение 1080х1920 в виджет размером 1080х1800 (за вычетом статусбара, навигационной панели и экшенбара). Дальнейшие действия системы по размещению этого изображения будут зависеть от параметра scale в виджете (fit, center, crop и др.) - по умолчанию изображение будет подогнано под меньшую сторону, чтобы войти в виджет целиком и соответственно пропорциям уменьшится и большая сторона - получится итоговое изображение 1012х1800 пикселей. Используя другие параметры атрибута scale можно получить другие способы "вписать" изображение в виджет.

PS:Если вы рассчитываете каким то образом получить точное соответствие по пикселям изображения с экранами всевозможных устройств, то это безнадежная задача и у вас определенно ничего не получится, максимум для одного конкретного устройства с определенным набором параметров. На другом устройстве, с незначительными отличиями параметров экрана уже ничего соответствовать не будет.

Подробнее о работе квалификаторов [смотрите этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453000/177345)

Comment: Оо,  шикарный ответ. Проблема была в том что я вроде всё правильно понимаю работу с папками для графики и что я должен маштабировать сам,а не система . А в результате мое изображение сжимает  и я грешил на не правильную работу с этими папками,  хотя дело в том что разметка как то влияет.  Почему разметка влияет я еще не понял. Т. к.  на экране остается свободное черное пространство, куда можно было вместить изображение, если бы не сжатие.

Comment: Да еще интересен тот  факт что изображения масшабируются с такой закономерностью.  Если deinsity = 2.5.  И изображение  с шириной 1080 лежит  в папке xxhdpi , то при загрузке в битмап получится 1080 * 2,5/3 =900 . Как будто  1080 уменьшая в 3 доводят до размера, который должен быть в mdpi и увеличивают в 2,5 раза и получают 900. Возможно совпадение.  А возможно я не понимаю разницу между density и scaledDensity , не подскажите в чем?

Comment: Что именно и как вы делаете с изображением, добавьте код в вопрос

Comment: Добавил код , вроде разметка не причем. В разметке стоит match_parent и на некоторых устройствах где deinsty = 3 , разметка не ограничивает, а на устройстве с deinsty 2,5 остаются черный не заполненные края в разметке

Comment: Может вы ошибаетесь и изображения всё таки масштабируются ? Просто выбирается самая близкая по плотности папка и масштабируется.

Comment: Вроде немного прояснилось. От плотности 2 до 3 ресурсы берутся из папки xxhdpi. Значит на fullhd экране при плотности 3 , ширина ресурса тоже должна быть 1080 ,чтобы занять всю ширину. Если плотность например 2,5 , то 3/2,5*1080 = 1296 ширина ресурса. Если коэффициент плотности 2 (т.е. еще больше пикселей в одном дюйме, а именно 560) , то ширина ресурса должна быть 1620,чтобы занять весь экран. И тут вот что замечаю, выходит 1620 пикселей изображения, может при плотности в 560 пикселей на дюйм помешается в 1080 пикселей экрана. Значит пиксели изображения виртуальны..

Comment: И когда я вызываю bitmap.getWidth() я получаю ширину в реальных пикселях. Т.е. изображение шириной 1080 пикселей , на экране с шириной в 1080 пикселей и плотность в 560 пиксель на дюйм , занимает 900 экранных пикселей. Поясните .что я не так сказал. Осталось мне гармонично вписать и то что изображения в цифровом виде тоже имеют свою плотность ppi. НАдо выспаться и еще раз подумать)