# Как адаптировать приложение на все экраны смартфонов?

Tags: адаптивность, экран

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу научиться адаптировать приложение под любой разрешение экрана. В последнее время, стали популярны нестандартные разрешение(вытянутые) и я хочу что бы приложения выглядели везде одинаково. Но я не понимаю,как размещать объекты,спрайты итд.итп. на экране,от чего нужно отталкиваться задавая координаты.
Как нужно делать структуру размещения?

Comment: В зависимости от того, что значит "одинаково" (пропорции? размер в px? размер в dp?), делать структуру размещения нужно по-разному. PS. На картинке преднамеренно неправильные пропорции?

Comment: «я хочу что бы приложения выглядели везде одинаково» — имхо, зря хотите

Comment: Ну,вот,смотрите,допустим у меня есть меню,в котором из-за краев экрана в видимую область перемещаются три объекта:"название приложения сверху вниз и две кнопки с правого и левого края экрана",мне нужно задать координаты так,чтобы на всех экранах между ними было одинаковое расстояние,а не так,что на одном экране между ними марианская впадина,а в другом все слиплось. Да,картинка нарисованная от руки.

Comment: Возможно, в [этом вопросе и ответах на него](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/452913/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2) найдется полезная информация или хотя бы ссылки на нее.

Comment: Как я понимаю,какого-то единого метода нет и нужно делать приложение изначально под разные экраны одновременно/параллельно,задавать диапазон получаемого размера экрана от этого и в дальнейшем строить структуру,поправьте,если не так.