# Хранение изображений в Drawable, как сэкономить размер

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, храню иконки в каталогах drawable, хочу в целях экономии размера apk и памяти телефона хранить их всего в двух папках, это drawable-xhdpi и drawable-xxhdpi, а не во всех пяти . Если устройство будет для большего или меньшего масштабирования (xxxhdpi, hdpi, mdpi) и в этих папках нет изображений, то андроид сам их возьмет и смасштабирует из тех что имеются? Или как?

Comment: [смотрите ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453000/177345) по работе android с папками ресурсов с квалификаторами.  Если хотите экономить размер приложения - используйте векторные изображения

Comment: и да, система возьмет ближайший подходящий размер и смаcштабирует под нужный. Проблема тут будет такая, что устройство с, например, hdpi-экраном и оперативной памятью 512 МБ не сможет "развернуть" ваше xhdpi-изображение в Bitmap для работы (потому что оно имеет большой для такого объема оперативной памяти размер и вес) и упадет по Out of Memory error. Так же такие устройства обладают слабым процессором и масштабирование огромных для них изображений будет тяжким бременем. То есть владельцы бюджетных устройств вместо вашей чудесной программы получат падучее и лагучее недоразумение